# What do Storage Caverns do?

Tags: shark-game

I've gotten to the point in [Shark Game](http://cirri.al/sharks/#) that I can purchase a Storage Cavern, but its effects are listed as ???

[image]

What does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It unlocks the Grotto, where you can view your collected resources and even discard them (which turns scientists back into normal sharks).  I haven't yet determined if there's an actual advantage to discarding resources, but I'm pretty new to the game (your question introduced me to it).

[image: Shark Grotto]